# Old code was working earlier today overlapping symbols css code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had this working earlier today

https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/sxaz9g34/130/

Its suppose to be a rectangle inside of a circle. it was perfectly aligned in the circle

code:

```
<html>
<body>

<script>

  document.write("<span class='parent'><span class='child r'> &#9645;</span>"+"<span class='child c'>&#9711;</span></span>".fontsize(4)+"<br>");

</script>
Determine the area of the largest rectangle that can be inscribed in a circle of radius 4.
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
.parent{

position : relative
}
.child.c{
position : absolute

}
.child.r{
   left : 2px;
position : absolute
}
```

I expect my output to be a rectangle inside a circle ( for a optimization problem). But my actual output it isn't neatly inside the circle( before i left school today it was perfect I must of saved the wrong version).

Comment: Not sure I understand: are you not using revision control to make sure you can just roll back to earlier today and compare what you had then to what you have now? If not: **start using revision control** (git, svg, hg, even if you only write code locally, this is still literally what they're for: taking snapshots of your files while things work, so you have something to roll back to when they end up no longer working)

Comment: trying to figure out what i messed up . what I have is similar to what i was given to make this illusion possible. not sure what went wrong. so 1 symbol is on the bottom and 2nd one is on top then i made the circle bigger then moved the rectangle a bit over so it is in the center of the circle

Comment: Isn't it the space before the character `&#9645;` ?

Comment: IMHO, you have messed up at the point you decide to use css and text to make shapes. And if I get it correctly. `2px` is nothing close to *perfectly aligned in the circle*. Would you like to use `canvas`?

Comment: i tried canvas earlier might go back to using that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
<html>

  <body>

    <script>
      document.write("<span class='parent'><span class='child r'> &#9645;</span>" + "<span class='child c'>&#9711;</span></span>".fontsize(4) + "<br>");

    </script>
    <p>
    &nbsp;
    </p>
    Determine the area of the largest rectangle that can be inscribed in a circle of radius 4.
  </body>

</html>
```

Css File

```
.parent {

  position: absolute;
}

.child.c {
  position: relative;

}

.child.r {
  left: 2px;
  top: 7px;
  position: absolute;
}
```